# Is there a way to override @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) settings in @FetchProfile

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have an entity with one of the fields annotated with @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE). I can't (not allowed to) change that. Is it possible to override this by @FetchProfile?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like

```
@FetchOverride(association = "b", entity = A.class, mode = FetchMode.SELECT)
```

would do the trick. When supported...